# how to convert framework 4.6.1 class library to core 3.1?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1, .net-core-3.1

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="14.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$...." Condition="Exists('$.....')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProjectGuid>{DE7456FD-4BE4-4C9A-BA8C-9148EA6793A0}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>Lynx.Core</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>Lynx.Core</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.6.1</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

i used

```
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
```

and also used

```
<TargetFrameworks>netstandard1.6;dnxcore50</TargetFrameworks>
    <DefineConstants>$(DefineConstants);CORE</DefineConstants>
    <NetStandardImplicitPackageVersion>1.6.0</NetStandardImplicitPackageVersion>
    <TargetFrameworkIdentifiers>.NEtStandard;.NETCoreApp</TargetFrameworkIdentifiers>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v1.6</TargetFrameworkVersion>
```

this lines of code but it didn't worked. because whenever i build this code my system were hanging can anyone help me to solve this problem

Comment: first you need to change it to be an SDK-style project, i.e. a csproj that starts `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk"`; SDK-style projects can support netfx, .NET Core, .NET Standard, etc; but until you make it an SDK-style project: it uses the old build

Comment: how do i convert it?

Comment: honestly, I'd usually just create a new empty csproj in either the IDE or `dotnet new`, and translate/copy the bits I need (nothing that entiries for .cs files etc usually don't need to be migrated)

Answer (score 0):

The .NET Core 2.0 and later (including the latest version of .NET Core 3.1 and the upcoming .NET 5.0) has the project model of SDK project. These csproj/vbproj/fsproj files (depends on what language you used) always have this XML on its first line:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
```

These are the other notable differences in SDK project:

1. The SDK project doesn't have project GUID embedded, like the one you have: `<ProjectGuid>...</ProjectGuid>`. Also other XML elements are ignored, such as `AppDesignerFolder`, `RootNamespace`.
2. The SDK project cannot use `TargetFrameworkVersion` because this element is intended to be used by .NET Framework projects created within Visual Studio, this is whythe value in this element always refer to .NET Framework version.
3. The SDK project doesn't require separate debug/release condition by default.

There is no tool to automate/help converting non-SDK project to SDK project. Therefore manual editing is required.

The detailed step-by-step instruction is available on this doc link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/migration/#migration-from-earlier-net-core-csproj-formats-to-rtm-csproj